# QTableView re-focus the view to specific column

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a QTableView with 80+ columns displayed in it. The subclass i have created for QTableView allows has functionality for the standard table stuff i wanted e.g order by columns move columns and rows hide column and rows etc.

However the problem i have is the view's focus. lets say you have all the data in the table, you scroll all the way to the right so you are looking at columns 70-80 (assuming 10 columns fit on the screen at once) if i click the header of row 80 (to order by column 80) the table reorders (as expected) however it also jumps the view to the last focused cell (which as far as i can tell is the cell that was last clicked)

What i want to do is not necessarily refocus on the column that was clicked because this might still change the view what im looking for is to just keep the view's focus exactly as it is instead of having it jump back to where the last clicked cell was?

Is there some flag im missing for focus policy or will i need to get the current view and set the view back to that view after mouse clicks that reorder the table and if so how could this be done.

Im aware i have provided no code for this question but it doesnt seem there is any needed since its not a bug im looking to fix more of a feature im unaware of, if you want to see any just comment

EDIT:

Im using a QSortFilterPorxyModel, this seems to get set once (when i call `this->setSortingEnabled(true);` after the initial call to this on contruction my table model never calls sort again. I have a slot linked to the header clicked signal, and i set the scroll bars to `scrollTo()` to the index clicked, but i think the sort is happening after this so it does nothing, any idea of what signal are emitted after sorting so i can catch them and then set the view back maybe?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you do your sort, store the current values for where the scroll bars are with

```
int vPos = yourQTableView->verticalScrollBar()->sliderPosition();
int hPos = yourQTableView->horizontalScrollBar()->sliderPosition();
```

then after the sort, set it back

```
yourQTableView->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(vPos);
yourQTableView->horizontalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(hPos);
```

The signals you are looking for are signals of QSortFilterProxyModel inherited from QAbstractItemModel:

```
layoutAboutToBeChanged()
layoutChanged()
```

Comment: Im sure this would work perfectly but i cant seem to get any signal that happens after the sorting (which is what makes it jump the view to the last focused cell), dont know how QSortFilterPorxyModel is working must be getting a signal from the click but it seems to be running after any other signals i catch like `SortIndicatorChanged` `HeaderClicked` `SectionClicked`

Comment: Ok so it turns out my issue was a function to resize columns to contents after layout had changed was hiding and showing the table so this was thr problem cheers for the answer thought with the information provided it seemed like the way to do it

Comment: I'm glad I could help!  I've been using this site for years as a reference but just started contributing.  I'm actually probably more excited to be of real help for the first time than you are that your problem is fixed :D

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't reproduce your symptoms by creating a `QTableWidget`, filling it up with random stuff, and then sorting a particular column.  The selected cell stays selected, but does not become visible if it has scrolled off screen.

So the question is, what is causing the behavior you're seeing.  It sounds as though `scrollTo()` is being called by some other function.  Since that's a virtual function, I would override it with a pass-through function and see when it's getting called.

Comment: Im not using QTableWidget im using QTableView and scroll to was simply a function i thought i could call after sorting to get the view back to where it was, but like i said it didnt work and is now removed

Comment: @AngryDuck `QTableWidget` inherits from QTableView; so they should share their behaviors.  Since they don't, something strange is happening.  And I still think you should try overloading the `scrollTo` function to see if somehow it's getting called by some other part of code.  If it is, you don't have to pass that along.